# Сообщение от сервера

Tags: android, ios

Добрый день!

У меня возник вопрос - каким образом мессенджеры (например, WhatsApp, Viber, Telegram и тд) передают на устройства сообщения? Push уведомления? Websocket?

Может кто-то задвался подобным вопросом? Или кто-то участвовал в подобных проектах?
Может есть статьи с описание алгоритмов?

Спасибо

Comment: APNS на ios, Google Cloud Messaging на android. Делали практически все, кто разрабатывает на этих платформах.

Comment: спасибо, буду в эту сторону копать!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это называется Push уведомления. Многие (если не все) облачные платформы умеют это делать. Кроме упоминавшегося Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) есть например облачная платформа [Amazon Web Services (AWS)](http://aws.amazon.com/ru/), есть облачко [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) - он вообще заточен конкретно под пуш, Apple также  имеет свой пуш [Apple Push Notification (APN)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html) - ну и т.д.